# AngularJS inject complete event is needed

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am defining a service in AngularJS 1.2.x like below where I inject the DreamFactory API for use in this service. Now, when I do this, I get the error message like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRecords' of undefined
```

I interprete that the injection has not completely terminated. So I went ahead and delayed the call to the API 1000ms which solves the problem. But of course, this delay is not an acceptable solution.
Somehow I need an event for injection completion upon which I can then launch the DreamFactory.api.db.getRecord() method.

Can anyone help?

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('VisitService', VisitService);

        VisitService.$inject = ['$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'DreamFactory'];
        function VisitService($cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, DreamFactory) {

            var service = {};

            service.getVisits = getVisits;


                function getVisits(callback) {

                    //setTimeout(function(){

                        DreamFactory.api.db.getRecords({table_name: 'visitors'})
                        .then(function(result) {

                          console.log(result.data.record);
                          callback(result.data.record)
                         },


                         function(reject) {


                         });
                    //}, 1000);


                }

                return service;


        }
```

})();

in the controller, I call the service like so

```
VisitService.getVisits(function(result){ 
        alert("this callback was triggered")
        console.log(result)
    });
```

Comment: You need to check `DreamFactory` - somewhere along the line there is no `db` object; hence the message.\

Comment: Hey Darren, I use to declare DreamFactory like...........                                   var loginApp = angular
    .module('app', [
        'ngRoute', 
        'ngCookies',
        'ngDreamFactory'
    ])
    .constant('DSP_URL', 'http://localhost:8080')
    .constant('DSP_API_KEY', 'myApp')

Comment: and, I nicely get my data when I have the small 1000ms delay added.

Comment: or, if I trigger the getVisit() with a button. It works nicely, no special delay needed. Hence this lets me think that DreamFactory has not been injected completely when I want to you the getRecords() method on it already. Then  it says that it cannot read a property of getRecords() which is not defined

Comment: No - there is no such thing as "injection completed"... Show us what happens in `DreamFactory` - clearly `db` is set asynchronously, which is why it is defined after a timeout. But there is no way for us to help if you don't post the code where the problem actually occurs (And please, edit the question with code - don't post in comments... and please, post only relevant code)

Answer (score 1):

DreamFactory uses, besides being a promise based API, another condition that one has to look for.

I do this with :

```
$scope.$on('api:ready', function (e) {  }
```

This watcher being present solves my problem.
Thanks everybody who tried to help